# If using GET variable only to see if isset, do I need to escape it?

Tags: php, get, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

Do I need to escape variables if they are used only for running through isset()?

Comment: What do you mean "escaping" variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're going to later insert that value into a database, there's nothing they can do. `isset("test');DROP TABLE users;--");` would return "true", but do absolutely nothing.

If you are planning on using it later however, use `addslashes()` or `mysql_real_escape_string`.

But no, isset cannot do anything bad.

Comment: Where is `strip_tags()` and `htmlentities()`?

Comment: @Shef My examples were solely for SQL injection, and irrelevant anyway because the OP's question was just about `isset()`

Answer (score 1):

No, using the PHP `isset` function is safe from SQL injection regardless of the value.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will need to escape external input mostly when using it in database queries and when outputting the content.

Answer (score 0):

No. Isset() would check the return value of your escaping function btw. ;)